# C# parse string to get desired format

Tags: c#

Trying to parse this:

```
Copy11-1-11111-3476cf30e7-18e8-48d8-841e-f215db307cdeOctTue1533152015-res.xml
```

and get

```
11-1-11111-3476cf30e7-18e8-48d8-841e-f215db307cdeOctTue1533152015.xml
```

How do I remove the "copy" in the beginning and "-res" at the end?

Comment: RegEx?  [`String.Replace`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1.aspx)?  pick your poison.

Comment: if this is fixed width you can use      String.Substring()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE:** If you're going to have `Copy` and / or `-res` in between the string and would want to preserve them. The following is not the best answer. You **will** have to use Regex.

But, if you're looking for something simplistic and want to replace **all occurrences** of `Copy` and `-res`, here is how you do it -

```
"Copy11-1-11111-3476cf30e7-18e8-48d8-841e-f215db307cdeOctTue1533152015-res.xml".Replace("Copy", "").Replace("-res","");
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/i3vvGq

Comment: It's actually `-res` at the end.

Comment: Thanks. Changed the answer

Comment: It is not entirely correct with String.Replace as we may got "Copy" and "-res" somewhere in the middle like: Copy11-1-111-res-343434-Copy-xxxxx-res.xml
Should use RegEx instead.

Comment: Nope! You're wrong.. Try it in the dotnetfiddle link and let me know what you get..

Comment: @AswinRamakrishnan: I mean they want to keep the other "Copy" words to be in the middle. If you replace all then you do remove it.

Comment: Ok.. My apologies.. Your comment / answer wasn't clear.. Yes! String.Replace will replace all occurences of Copy and -res. But his pattern seems pretty simplistic.. If he wants to keep Copy and -res in between the string, Regex would be the best option (Updated my answer btw, Thanks!)

Answer (score 1):

Many people suggest to use `String.Replace` but that may not entirely correct as we may got `"Copy"` and `"-res"` string appear somewhere in the middle.

You could try to use Regular Expression instead:

```
string inputStr = "Copy11-1-11111-3476cf30e7-18e8-48d8-841e-f215db307cdeOctTue1533152015-res.xml";

var groups = Regex.Match(inputStr, "^Copy(.*)-res.xml$").Groups;        
var group1 = groups[1].Value;            

var output = group1 + ".xml";
```

Try it: https://dotnetfiddle.net/2AVM3i

Comment: I agree with Minh.  The original question specifically says "How do I remove the "copy" in the **beginning** and "-res" at the **end**?"  It doesn't say that those values will **not** appear somewhere in the middle.  Using Replace() would change all occurrences, which might cause problems if those values appeared elsewhere in the string.  Without knowing how that entire string is generated, can you say that it is impossible for those values to appear in the middle?

Comment: If you think it is useful can you please vote for the answer :d

Answer (score 0):

To remove those occurrence of substring you want to remove, it's fairly easy to do when you find the index of the substring inside the string.

```
int index = sourceString.IndexOf("Copy11-");
string withFirstRemoved = (index < 0)
? sourceString
: sourceString.Remove(index, removeString.Length);
```

Then you follow by the same but for the other string
-res

```
int newIndex = sourceString.IndexOf("-res");
string withFirstRemoved = (index < 0)
? sourceString
: sourceString.Remove(newIndex, withFirstRemoved.Length);
```

But a better way to do so would be to use a method so if you need to remove other stuff later, it's pretty flexible ! :)

**UPDATE**

Indeed, based on the comments I received, the solution was a bit long. Using Replace instead with CleanStringFromSubstrings will give you the flexibility to remove substring for any string and substrings you might encounter later, not just for the problem you have at the moment!

```
    public string CleanStringFromSubstrings(string original,params string[] listStr)
    {
        foreach (var subStr in listStr)
        {
            original = original.Replace(subStr, "");
        }
        return original;
    }
```

Comment: An amazing amount of code for something that can be done in one line!

Comment: I gave this if he wanted to remove other substrings. Things could be automated later

Comment: @DavidG modified answer, you were right ! Made the appropriate changes :)

Answer (score 0):

find both substrings and replace them both with empty strings.

```
myString = myString.Replace("Copy", string.Empty).Replace("-res", string.Empty);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the String FirstIndexOf and LastIndexOf methods to get the position of the starting character for the strings you're trying to remove 'Copy11-' and '-res'.  Once you have the indexes of those, use the Substring method to get everything after the 'Copy11-', then use Substring again to get everything before and after the '-res'.